# jsf 2 Session bean created for every request

Tags: jsf-2

ello

I have 2 Managed beans, one View scoped, the other Session scoped. The View scoped bean is defined as

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class InvoiceController implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @ManagedProperty(value="#{invoiceService}")
  private InvoiceService invoiceService;
```

The session scoped bean as

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class InvoiceService implements Serializable{
```

I am using the session scoped bean to hold a flag used to decide if a panel should be rendered, when I run this through the debug I find that every time I call the method on the sesison bean, it is a new instance of the bean and therefore does not retain the value of my flag between requests.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9):

That can happen if you have imported `@SessionScoped` from the [`javax.enterprise.context`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/context/SessionScoped.html) package instead of from the [`javax.faces.bean`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/SessionScoped.html) package. The former works on CDI [`@Named`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Named.html) beans only, while the latter works on JSF [`@ManagedBean`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ManagedBean.html) beans only.

A JSF `@ManagedBean` without any valid scope would default to [`@NoneScoped`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/NoneScoped.html) which means that it's newly constructed on every single EL expression referencing the bean, such as the [`@ManagedProperty`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ManagedProperty.html). This explains the symptoms you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks BalusC, I have checked the import and it is javax.faces.bean package.

Comment: Then you've a bigger problem. Is your view scoped bean also recreated or maintained? Are you using server or client side state saving? Is the session cookie properly maintained across subsequent requests?

Comment: Wow, and this is when I'm trying to do the simple bits. I will check - thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I use a save-method in the view scoped bean that calls a method in the session scoped bean to update some values.

This is what I found out by debugging (excuse my non-Java-guru English):

When first loading the page, the instance number of the injected session bean was for example 111111.
But in the save-method (and all other methods called by an action like a commandButton or action listeners btw), suddenly the session bean was of another instance (say 222222).

Both instances 111111 and 222222 contained the very same values. 
All methods I called now were done in the 222222 instance and it changed values in there as I wanted it. But the 111111 instance remained untouched and unchanged.

So 222222 was basically a deep(?) clone of 111111, and not even a copy.

But, after the save-method was done and the page got reloaded, the original 111111 instance was used again in the view scope bean.
The 222222 instance just got thrown to the garbage.

**My solution for this problem:**

I'm not using the ManagedProperty injection anymore.

Instead I made some helper code to get the session bean wherever I need it (aka in the view scoped bean methods):

```
public Object getSessionBean(String sessionBeanName)
    {
        return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getELResolver().getValue(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext(), null, sessionBeanName);
    }
```

For your example above, the call would be:

InvoiceService invoiceService = (InvoiceService) helper.getSessionBean("invoiceService");

Call it in your methods, do not store it as a field in the view scoped bean.

I hope this somehow helps you fix your problem.